# Adding a Job Aid (like a course) to Category

Tags: moodle

I wanted add a Job Aid which is like a course for a Category in Moodle. For Example PMP is a Category, Course is details which runs for 4 to 5 days. Job Aid is a brush up Course which runs for 2 to 3 hours.
Can this be achieved? If yes then how?
Please help.
With Rgds,
Anil[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjj2E.png)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me - can you explain it differently please?

Comment: Can you please look at the attached Image? Like Course I wanted to add Job Aid to the same category.